# BlazeDS on GAE (Detected duplicate HTTP-based FlexSessions)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blazeds

Is BlazeDS 4 work with Google App Engine. I'm using BlazeDS 3.2.0 and getting an such an error

```
Detected duplicate HTTP-based FlexSessions, generally due to the remote host disabling session cookies. Session cookies must be enabled to manage the client connection correctly.
```

Is it possible to point out a place where I can download the compiled blzeds jar files that work with GAE since I'm facing troubles downloading the source code from the site(slow internet connection at a place I work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need messaging do not use BlazeDS on Google App Engine. For remoting, several guys created some patches. One is [here](http://martinzoldano.blogspot.com/2009/04/appengine-adobe-blazeds-fix.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't use it for messaging. I also just downloaded compiled patch from http://code.google.com/p/s3blazeds/